# Sort data in a table using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, cursor

we had a chalenge question in a test we did at school,that we to create a t-sql script which sort data in a table by the employees salary using a cursor without using another table or using the clause ORDER BY .

No one did it because as I said it was a challenge question, I'm trying to do it at home but unfortunately I didn't do much progress so any help will be more that appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: it's sql server 2008,  is it important to decide what is the version of sql server ?

Comment: Please post the progress you've made so far

Comment: What result do you expect?  Tables aren't "sorted".

Comment: I'll echo what HABO said. Order in SQL is arbitrary without an ORDER BY, by definition.

Comment: I suspect that Su Sha is saying that the challenge is to implement a sorting algorithm in TSQL, rather than using `ORDER BY`. So the question might be better phrased as "how do I implement bubble sort/Quicksort/whatever in TSQL"? It's a common learning exercise in many programming languages, after all, although not usually in SQL.

Comment: @Pondlife - Agreed, in part.  The question remains as to the definition of "result".  Is it setting a column to a value that is equivalent to `ROW_NUMBER()` with an `ORDER BY` clause?  Is it doing a `PRINT` per row stating that the cursor is on the _n_ th row in salary order?  (Hint: The count of rows with smaller salary values + 1.)

Comment: Since this is the type of thing you should NEVER do in a cursor, why do you want to figure it out? This strikes me as a completely useless challenge and one that encourages you to learn the wrong things.

Answer (score 1):

i go in line that it is **absolutely** the wrong way to order data this way - anyway, this approach does what OP asked for. 
And yes - the cursor is definetly superfluous, because you can run the inner query without the last `WHERE` clause to have an ordering without using `ORDER BY`. Only added it to go along with original question.

```
--CREATE TABLE salary( emplId int, salary int );
--INSERT INTO salary VALUES( 4, 150), (2, 100), (3, 200), (1, 10);

DECLARE @emplId INT;
DECLARE @runs INT = 0;

DECLARE sal CURSOR
FOR SELECT EmplId FROM "salary" 
OPEN sal

FETCH NEXT FROM sal INTO @emplId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        S."emplId", S."salary"
    FROM 
        "salary" AS S 
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT COUNT( "salary" ) AS "successors" 
                  FROM "salary" 
                  WHERE "salary" < S."salary" ) AS Data 
    WHERE 
        Data."successors" = @runs 

    SET @runs +=1

    FETCH NEXT FROM sal INTO @emplId
END

CLOSE sal
DEALLOCATE sal;
```

Comment: Interesting results when several employees have the same salary.  I like it.

Comment: what's interesting? "ordering" is also correct, if many or all have same salary, isn't it? see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0138/3/0). just removed cursor because fiddle doesn't seem to like it!